PowerShell wont work as admin with double quotes
The problem is that the '-Verb RunAs' wont work with '\"' for some reason
and I need the quotes for better handeling of paths
:: Check for admin privilage
openfiles > nul 2>&1
if !errorlevel! neq 0 (
    echo | set /p="The execution needs elevated privileges (y|n)"
    choice /n
    if !errorlevel! equ 1 (
        start /b /wait PowerShell -Command "Start-Process '%~f0' -ArgumentList '%res% -ico \"%icon%\" -dir \"%directory%\"' %style% -Verb RunAs"
        exit /b
    )
)


when I remove one of them the other works
::like this
start /b /wait PowerShell -Command "Start-Process '%~f0' -ArgumentList '%res% -ico \"%icon%\" -dir \"%directory%\"' %style%"

::or this
start /b /wait PowerShell -Command "Start-Process '%~f0' -ArgumentList '%res% -ico %icon% -dir %directory%' %style% -Verb RunAs"

Or when I convert it into an executable it works
I don't know why is that happening maybe a glitch or something
I hope someone finds a solution

Please do not tag spam. PowerShell is not Windows batch file or Spring batch or any of the other batch tags you added, and just because tags have the word "batch" in it doesn't mean that they are anywhere near the same thing. Your question is specifically about PowerShell, and that is the only tag that applies to your question. I've removed the other inappropriate tags. Tag spamming is a very good way to quickly collect downvotes and get your question closed. Tags have relevance and meaning here - please use them properly.

@KenWhite, while some of the original tags where definitely inapplicable, batch-file does apply, so I've restored it: you must satisfy the (batch-file) syntax the requirements of cmd.exe too, not just PowerShell's, so the environment that the PowerShell CLI is called from matters.

@KenWhite: Your comment doesn't address my feedback, whose gist is: you need to take two languages into account here, which is why both tags are appropriate. I've flagged your actions for moderator intervention, by way of your most recent comment.

@KenWhite :: Check for admin privilage is definitely a batch comment. Same to if !errorlevel! neq 0 (), set /p, start /b or !errorlevel! which are all cmd things. The OP is calling PowerShell from cmd, which doesn't mean the only language here is PowerShell. Who said that the batch part wouldn't have any bugs?

if !errorlevel! neq 0 could be if errorlevel 1; echo | set /p="The execution needs elevated privileges (y|n)" and choice /n could be just choice /m "The execution needs elevated privileges"; if !errorlevel! equ 1 could be if not errorlevel 2; and start /b /wait should be start "" /b /wait.

My general advice: avoid the whole Escaping Double Quotes in Batch Script debacle by putting everything under the PowerShell hood: e.g. by creating a self-elevating PowerShell script

@mklement0, I tried SET ArgumentList=%res% -ico \"%icon%\" -dir \"%directory%\" and start /b /wait PowerShell -Command "Start-Process '%~f0' -ArgumentList $Env:ArgumentList %style% -Verb RunAs".  This problem still persist.  Also tried PWSH, same issue.  But it works if I use SET ArgumentList=ABC.  It is as if Start-Process dies if -RunAs is used with an argument list that contains a \\ in it.

@mklement0, my comment appears to be incorrect.  It looks like it is NOT the backslash, but the double quotes that -Verb RunAs has a problem with.


To spell it out: You're trying to create a self-elevating batch file, i.e. one that reinvokes itself with elevated (administrative) privileges while passing arguments through.
You appear to have hit a bug where reinvoking a batch file with arguments that are enclosed in "..." syntactically breaks the invocation of the target process when elevation is requested via PowerShell's Start-Process -Verb RunAs. I don't know for sure, but I suspect that the bug is at a level below PowerShell.
The workaround is to call the batch file via cmd.exe /C and to enclose the entire argument list passed to the latter in "..." overall, in addition to the "..." enclosure of individual arguments

To provide a simple example: the process command line that must ultimately be launched has to look something like this - note the - unescaped - outer "..." that encloses the double-quoted batch-file path and all pass-through arguments, which may be individually double-quoted:
"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /c ""c:\path\to\my.cmd" -foo "bar""



Here's a self-contained, streamlined demonstration of the workaround, incorporating incidental improvements suggested by Compo.
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: ...

:: Check for admin privileges
net sessions > nul 2>&1 || (
  choice /m "The execution needs elevated privileges"
  if !errorlevel! equ 1 (
        echo Relaunching with elevation and arguments and waiting for completion...
        start /b /wait "" PowerShell -NoProfile -Command "Start-Process -Wait -Verb RunAs cmd.exe -ArgumentList '/C \"\"%~f0\" %res% -ico \"%icon%\" -dir \"%directory%\"\"' %style%"
        exit /b
  ) else (
        echo Elevation request declined. >&2
        exit /b 1
  )
)

:: Getting here means that the batch file runs elevated.

echo Running elevated; args given: [%*]

pause


That is a solide answer and it worked, thanks for helping

I'm glad to hear it, @benznega; my pleasure.
